# Reform: Dry-Validation Matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, reform, trailblazer

I'm looking for a convenient way to test validations of a [Reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform)-based form object.

Are there any matchers (like shoulda matchers for testing ActiveModel::Validations) to test [dry-validations](http://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/)? Is this even the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

There is this: [https://github.com/bloom-solutions/dry-validation-matchers](http://There%20is%20this:%20https://github.com/bloom-solutions/dry-validation-matchers%20%20I've%20enjoyed%20using%20shoulda%20matchers%20in%20the%20past.%20It%20helps%20to%20greatly%20cut%20down%20on%20the%20repetitive%20code%20where%20you%20first%20create%20a%20valid%20object%20and%20then%20change%20the%20attribute%20affected%20by%20the%20validation%20to%20an%20invalid%20value%20to%20carry%20out%20the%20test.%20%20In%20the%20end%20this%20is%20just%20a%20matter%20of%20taste.)

I've enjoyed using shoulda matchers in the past. It helps to greatly cut down on the repetitive code where you first create a valid object and then change the attribute affected by the validation to an invalid value to carry out the test.

In the end this is just a matter of taste.